# How do I add custom logs to a Visual Studio Team Services build's log output?

Tags: logging, build, automated-tests, azure-devops

[image]

When I look at a completed build in Visual Studio Team Services, I see it has a nice zip file with all the logs. This contains log files for all the build steps, which is very nice.

However, I want more. During automated test execution (using the Visual Studio Test task) I wish to stream all my diagnostic logs to file and to include it in this zip file. Where must I place my log files in order to actually include them in this zip file? Is there a pre-defined build system variable I can use to provide my test code this path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't any setting to achieve this feature for now. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

Currently, the basic information for test is already included in the logs in the zip file. And you can also turn on verbose output by setting "system.debug" to "true" for diagnostic when you queue the build.

[image]